# Java resources folder error sign spring mvc

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Please what does this error sign mean and how can I get rid of this error sign in my spring mvc application.
Screen shot shown below.

[image]

I noticed this immediately I altered my Spring facets in Spring MVC.

Comment: The jars in classpath not in linear with the project, update the project

Comment: Okay. That is what it means right?

Comment: I have done that with maven update. stilll its there

Comment: try maven install compile and finally clean the project

Comment: There is nothing like maven compile

Comment: Later you may right click project Maven > Update Project. If the symbol still exists, refresh the project using F5.

Comment: Have you checked the eclipse "Problems" tab to see what (if any) error is reported...?

Comment: How can I locate the problem tabs

Comment: Please when ever you encounter this kind of error, do check for libraries not supposed to be in the libraries folder. Or libraries whose path cannot be referenced Or libraries that is class and automatically converted to a jar and added to the classpath. Kindly remove the libraries then update and clean your maven.